# Updating UI from countDownTimer running in a service

Tags: android, android-intent

So, from what I understand, I should use intents to update the UI of an activity from a service.

But, I am a bit concerned about the efficiency of what I want to do.

Theoretically, it shouldn't really pose a serious problem, but I don't want to have a situation in which I wake up my phone, and have 20-30 `onTick`-s running at once, each time generating a new intent.

What I want (if possible) is for each `onTick`'s intent to overwrite the previous one, so that the receiver only has process one at a time.

I know pending intents have `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, but doing things the right way means (if I understand correctly) using a local broadcast, which doesn't work with pending intents.

Comment: `So, from what I understand, I should use intents to update the UI of an activity from a service.` no, you can use "bound service" pattern, and the most efficient is "bound local service" where you can pass objects directly (no IPC needed)

Comment: @pskink Oh, thank you. I actually looked into binding, but I didn't fully understand what it was, and when I looked for answers to my specific problem, people were mostly talking about intents. I will look into the binding thing again more deeply.

Comment: @user1999728, Kindly write the answer to this question once you figure out what you are doing, It would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be surprisingly simple.
A pskink suggested in his comment, all you need is a binder:

1. Create a class that extends the `Binder` class. Keep in mind that the `Binder` class implements `IBinder`, which is why you can pass an instance of your new class as an instance of `IBinder` (which is something you will be doing later on)
2. In this class, implement various functions you want your main activity to be able to use. If you want your service to be able to run things from the activity as well, you can pass an instance of an inner class of the activity, which has the relevant functions in it, or even pass a pointer to the activity (`this`).

**Keep in mind: Do these things at your own risk. If, for example, your activity is destroyed - for example, due a change of orientation, the pointers might become worthless and errors will be thrown**

I recommend implementing an `invalidate` inside your new class to help you handle these situations, but perhaps there are better practices I am not personally familiar with.

Now, you have a two-way communication channel with your activity.

Below is some sample code. Note that if you don't want your service to be destroyed when the activity is, you need (as far as I understand it) to also start it using `startService` (in addition to using `bindService`)

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private  IBinder yourBinder; //A class that will connect your service and your activity

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        yourBinder = new YourBinderClass();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return yourBinder;
    }
```

Your binder class:

```
public class YourBinderClass extends Binder {
    private Service thisService;
    public YourBinderClass(Service myService)
    {
        thisService = myService;
    }

    public Service getService()
    {
        return thisService;
    }
```

And finally, inside your main activity:

```
private YourBinderClass yourBinderClass;
private Service yourService;
private ServiceConnection sc = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            yourBinderClass = (YourBinderClass) service;
            yourService = yourBinderClass.getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        }
    };
```

And to launch the service:

```
getBaseContext().bindService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class), sc, 0)
```

Note that the service won't be ready immediately, so if your activity is dependent on it, you might want to signal that you are ready to do stuff in `onServiceConnected`